# Replace onclick button with image

Tags: html, button

How can I make the following buttons so that there is an image that works as a play button for my background music? So far I have:

```html
<audio id="player" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" src="file://C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\folder\cop\music\Rapsody.mp3"></audio>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"> Play </button> 
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
```

```
<audio id="player" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" src="file://C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\folder\cop\music\Rapsody.mp3"></audio>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"> Play </button> 
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
```

Comment: You know that the user/visitor also needs to place the file on the exact same location? Maybe the browser can't even access it

Comment: he never mention he had access issues @ Koen Hollander

Comment: What is happening, how many audio tags are there?? What happens when you click one, does only one always play??

Answer (score 0):

When you want to replace it with a image, you maybe can hide it and use a button to click it.

```
<audio id="player" style="display:none" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" src="file://C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\folder\cop\music\Rapsody.mp3"></audio>
```

And after above, you can add a image

```
<img src="x.png" onclick="$("#player").play();">
```

Did'nt test it, but i'm pretty sure that this works

Answer (score 0):

Using png icons:

```
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><img src="play.png"></button> 
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()"><img src="pause.png"></button>
```

Using Fontawesome icons library:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

   <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><i class="fa fa-play" style="font-size:2wv;"></i>
```

```
   <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()"><i class="fa fa-pause" style="font-size:2wv;"></i>
```

Bootstrap also has media icons too.